# Renaming shortcut filename doesn't reflect in the target file name. Why?

Tags: windows, microsoft-word

When I rename the shortcut filename, the new file name is not reflected in the target or reference file name or vice versa. Shorcut is on desktop and target file is on e drive. Why?

For eg.
Old shortcut filename is Asd.doc
Target file name is Asd.doc.

New shortcut filename is ASD.doc
Target filename is Asd.doc.

Same case is for folder renaming.

I need the new filename or folder name to be reflected in the target file or folder name respectively.

Please kindly help.

Comment: Windows has always been that way.

Comment: You can rename the target file and the Windows shortcut will find it and auto update. See https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/distributed-link-tracking-and-object-identifiers for rules.

Comment: That's too complicated...

Comment: What is complicated? Its automatic.

Answer (score 1):

The behavior described is "by design". The shortcut itself is a file with a distinctive name. It isn't dynamic based on the underlying filename.